# mingw-w64 compiler error using template function with lambda expression and trailing return type

Tags: templates, lambda, c++14, mingw-w64, trailing-return-type

While cross-compiling a program under Ubuntu 16.04 for Windows using mingw-w64 I came across this error.

Consider this minimal example program test.cc:

```
template <class E = void>
void call()
{
  auto l = [](auto&& cc) -> decltype(cc[0]) {};
}

int main()
{
  call<>();
}
```

Compilation using g++ (version 5.4.0)

```
g++ -std=c++14 test.cc -o test
```

works fine, however mingw (version 5.3.1)

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++-posix -std=c++14 test.cc -o test
```

produces an error message

```
test.cc: In instantiation of 'void call() [with E = void]':
test.cc:4:40: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer
    auto l = [](auto&& cc) -> decltype(cc[0]) {};
                                         ^
```

When omitting the template in the above example function, compilation succeeds.

Why does mingw produce a compiler error for this expression? Is there a way to reformulate the expression to avoid this error?

Comment: The mingw-w64 5.3.1 compilation fails because [GCC 5.3 compilation fails](https://godbolt.org/g/bfW7Ud). I'm afraid I can't suggest a rework.

Comment: Using the most recent g++ version of mingw-w64, this compiles without error